# How to use proxy in scrapy where proxies have different session id

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

Hi thanks for taking the time to read this, I have residential proxies that i want to use in scrapy but in scrapy documentation we have proxies like this

```
http://some_proxy_server:port or http://username:password@some_proxy_server:port
```

The proxies i have look like this

```
['username:password_session-xxxxx:some_proxy_server:port'
'username:password_session-xxxx1:some_proxy_server:port', 
'username:password_session-xxxx2_session:some_proxy_server:port']
```

so if you see normally proxy server and port change but username and password stay the same and we have list of server:port that rotates but when i start scraper with my proxies it only sends requests to some_proxy_server:port which is same for all the proxies but session is different, i have tried adding this in middleware, used these libraries but all these treat these proxies the same.

```
scrapy-rotated-proxy==0.1.5
scrapy-rotating-proxies==0.6.2
```

so my question is how do i use the proxies where we have different session_id instead of host and port

```
http://username@password-session_id@host:port
```

Update:
here is the middleware i used

```
with open('files/proxies.txt', 'r') as f:
    proxies = f.read()
    proxies=proxies.split('\n')

class CustomProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        print('_______', random.choice(proxies))
        request.meta["proxy"] = random.choice(proxies)
        request.headers["Proxy-Authorization"] = basic_auth_header("username", "password")
```

Comment: @Alexander I have tried all these i mentioned i provided list of proxies to scrapy-rotating-proxies and it only shows 1 checked and 999 unchecked and when search the terminal its only one proxy used over and over again, similarly i import proxy txt file in spider and ad it in meta['proxy'] but in response.meta is only see the server and port ip

Comment: I have added the middleware i used

Comment: What service is providing these proxies addresses?  Do they provide an api or documentation on how to use them?

Comment: actually this is the problem, its speedproxies they don't have documentations about how to use proxies or anything but i am able to r.meta['proxy']=random.choice(self.all_proxies) it kind of work but the problem is i have to configure rotate proxies, remove failed proxies etc manually it would be a lot easier if i could just use existing libraries

Comment: Check out https://speedproxies.net/proxy-formatter/  It looks like you can convert the proxy list to a different format

Comment: Its just parsing the proxies like and rearrange the user:pas_session@ip:port to  user:pas_session:ip:port doest do anything with sessionid

Comment: I suggest contacting their support team then and asking them

Comment: I was expecting some simple solution here but looks like that is the only option i have right now, anyway thanks for taking the time.. i appreciate it :)